# Unfortunately removed myself as plugin committer

Tags: plugins, author

Unfortunately I removed myself as plugin committer. I was only committer of my plugin. So that, I couldn't find any options to add me back again.

What can I do now?

Please Help.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the situation you are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an email to `plugins [at] wordpress.org`, and explain your problem. There is nothing you can do without their help.